# Embeding matplotlib in Tkinter Error

Tags: python, macros, matplotlib, tkinter

After a couple days I returned to my computer and noticed my graphing scripts no longer works, despite no changes being made to the graphing code or the computer libraries. I decided to investigate and the example script from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html) no longer works and throws this error

```
objc[34475]: Class TKApplication is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.6/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[34475]: Class TKMenu is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.6/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[34475]: Class TKContentView is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.6/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[34475]: Class TKWindow is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk and /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.6/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Upon the import mentioned below and the following fatal error uport running `Tk.Tk()`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/Projects/name/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    root = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1789, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError
```

I'm confused why is it pointing to my Brewed (I'm on Os X if this helps) python if I'm working in a virtual environment. It is worth noting that Tkinter and Matplotlib work separately, It's just the line

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
```

that breaks stuff.

EDIT1: I tired reinstalling Tcl, python and virtualenv. Nothing fixed the problem :(

EDIT2: Run the same thing in a python2 (innsted of 3) interpreter. Error was more verbose.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Resources/Scripts/tk.tcl: version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.9, need 8.6
version conflict for package "Tcl": have 8.5.9, need 8.6
    while executing
"package require Tcl 8.6"
    (file "/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Resources/Scripts/tk.tcl" line 14)
    invoked from within
"source /Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Resources/Scripts/tk.tcl"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel #0 [list source $file]"


This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

Ok so problem is to do with the Tcl thing. Which I haven't touched and it worked prevoiusly.

EDIT3: Tried a reinstall of [ActiveTcl](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl) - did not change anything

EDIT4: under `/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/` I have Tk versions 8,5 and 8.4 installed

under `/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/` I have version 8.6 installed.

I tried disabling version 8.6 to reflect the configuration on a different computer the script works on. Got this error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/ODE/virtenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_tkagg.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.6/Tcl
  Referenced from: /Users/mik/Desktop/Projects/ODE/virtenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_tkagg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Both computers use same Python version (3.4.1) and the same matplotlib version (1.3.1). Is there a way to specify which Tk/Tcl version matplotlib uses?

EDIT 6: I verified using Time Machine that none of the Tk/Tcl veriosn files changed since the last time the script ran.

EDIT 7: And kinda solution:

Copying the matplotlib folder from site-packages of the working computer to the one which displays those errors fixed the issue. I would be grateful to know how to set the tcl version used by matplotlib in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Matplotlib looks for the Tcl/Tk framework when its being installed. I temporarily disabled version 2.6, reinstalled matplotlib and re-enabled version 2.6. Works

Comment: I am having the same problem with a twist. I installed anaconda python and julia after that. I have detailed it here:      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984763/pyplot-error-after-installing-julia